# Docker automatically save events in file

Tags: docker

docker events doesn't save events in files. But I need to backup all history. In case of crash, I need to known the status of all container.

How to automatically save events in files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Docker logs all containers. Moe details about how to view logs can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/). However, there is another way to handle this thing.

When you start the docker, you can add `|& tee docker.log` to the command you use to start docker containers.

This stores all the logs being displayed on terminal inside a file named `docker.log`. This is described in more detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/731237/353904).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I can not use the logs, the system must be independent of the image. In addition, I must detect OOM, and events can detect them.

Comment: `|& tee docker.log` is unix based, and is independent of image! If you are getting confused, instead of using `docker.log` you can use `logs.txt`. Checkout the last link, probably that would make it more clear

Comment: My container doesn't output any things. There are no log, so the file docker.log is empty...

Comment: Are you using a `-d` flag to run the container? Because that detaches the console after running the container. Have you tried _not_ using `-d` flag?

Comment: I use `docker run --memory=1g --cpus=1 my_image:latest |& tee docker.log`